# C++ - my for loop is not starting

Tags: c++, for-loop

I wrote this code for java first. It should print the 2D array as a spiral. I wanted to try it in c++.. in java; there was a draw method. But c++ is not accepting array as a return type (can done by pointers) so I deleted the draw method and copied inside the main method. I commented the draw method where starts and ends. But now; the for loop which is after the draw method (i commented it too) is not starting. What's the problem; I cannot see it... Thanx for help.

```
int T ;
scanf("%d", &T);
int num[T];
for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
}

for(int m = 0; m < T; m++){
    int n = num[m];
    int a[n][n];


    //draw -start
    int all = n*n;
    int x = 0, y=0;


    for(int counter=1; counter<=all; counter++){

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            a[x][y] = counter++;
            y++;}
        x++; y--;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            a[x][y] = counter++;
            x++;}
        x--; y--;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            a[x][y] = counter++;}
        x--; y++;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++){
            a[x][y] = counter++;}

        y++; x++; n = n-2;}

    //draw - end
   //this for is not starting
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("a");
        for(int j = 0; i<n; j++){
            printf("a");
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");

    }
```

Comment: this won't even compile, where is counter declared?

Comment: sorry; i changed the code when i was writing here. i forgot to write int before it.

Comment: And what is n? It's decremented after the first four for(!) loops, then  used in the one that doesn't work. If it's less than 2 at the start, that loop won't have anything to do...

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and step through it a line at a time. You will see exactly what it is doing and understand your problem. Use e.g. `gdb`. Compile with `-g` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah, i see it now =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decrement `n` in the biggest cycle.

```
n = n-2;
```

This is why `n` < 0 when you reach the `for` you speak of and it is not looping.

I am almost certain you did not meant to modify `n` in this loop.

Comment: Once you've fixed that, you'll want to correct the inner loop to `for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){` (currently `i<n`)

Comment: These errors are normal. When I was trying to find the problem; I changed some codes but without attention =) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I neatened up your code and provided my answer in the comments.

```
int T ;
scanf("%d", &T);
int num[T];
for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
}

for(int m = 0; m < T; m++){
    int n = num[m];
    int a[n][n];


    //draw -start
    int all = n*n;
    int x = 0, y=0;


    for(counter=1; counter<=all; counter++){

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[x][y] = counter++;
            y++;
        }
        x++; 
        y--;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            a[x][y] = counter++;
            x++;
        }
        x--; 
        y--;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            a[x][y] = counter++;
        }
        x--; 
        y++;

        for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
            a[x][y] = counter++;
        }

        y++; 
        x++; 
        n = n-2;  //n = n - 2; all = n * n times?
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("a");
        for(int j = 0; i<n; j++){
            printf("a");
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

in particular look at this line

```
n = n-2;  //n = n - 2; all = n * n times?
```

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do it but in this way, it's necessary.

Comment: This answer is identical to the answer you accepted?  I think I understand your problem now.